# How to exclude data which is already matched to the other table? MySQL CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to create a report of not submitted grades and fetch all data of not submitted grades.

I have two tables, `tbl_college_grades` and `tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo`

1st table - `tbl_college_grades` - fetch data which have grades

2nd table - `tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo` - fetch data with all subjects info

I need to hide or exclude data in `tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo` in which `tbl_college_grades` already have.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Here is my model and query, I have tried to use NOT EXISTS but here is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'EXISTS(SELECT tbl_college_grades.subCode FROM tbl_college_grades
> WHERE tbl_co...'

Code:

```
function report(){
    $this->db->join('tbl_college_grades','tbl_college_grades.subCode = tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subjectCode','left');
    $this->db->group_by('subject');
    $this->db->where('NOT EXISTS(SELECT tbl_college_grades.subCode FROM tbl_college_grades WHERE tbl_college_grades.subCode = tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subjectCode)');
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

#### [Preview in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49b7d1/2)

> `$this->db->group_by('tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subject');` use proper table to subject. I assumed it was placed in `tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo`

```
function report(){
    $this->db->select('tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo');
    $this->db->join('tbl_college_grades', 'tbl_college_grades.subCode = tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subjectCode', 'left');
    $this->db->where('NOT EXISTS (Select tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subjectCode from tbl_college_grades WHERE tbl_college_grades.subCode = tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subjectCode');
    $this->db->group_by('tbl_fm_college_curriculuminfo.subject');
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

---

> `group_by` always comes at last (before data fetch `->get()`)

Comment: hello sir, it does give an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '` after testing your query. Is there a way around to fix this please? thank you very much